# QTextStream verify status

Tags: c++17, qt5

Using Qt 5.11

In a legacy project I found the following code.

```
void parse(QTextStream& stream)
{
   if (stream.status() != QTextStream::Status::ok)
     throw std::runtime_error("error");

   // code
}
```

I expected the below unit test to throw an exception when checking status() method but that did not happen. The status method returns "Ok" in this case.

```
QTextStream stream;
parse(stream);
```

How should I check if QTextStream is in a good state?

Standard C++ streams uses iostate (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) which seems a sensible solution. I cannot find similar functionality in QTextStream.

Does it make sense to check device() method and if it returns nullptr then the stream is not valid?